# Android OkHttp Basic Auth with session cookie

Tags: cookies, session-cookies, basic-authentication, okhttp

I am using OkHttp 3.x, and I need to authenticate to a server via Basic Auth. The server returns a `JSESSIONID` cookie upon successful authentication.

I have setup a `CookieJar` to store the returned cookie, and to send it back to the server (and it is well received).

However, at the moment I send the credentials via headers, and even though i send the cookie, the Basic Auth credentials are still sent.

**How can I send the Basic Auth credentials only if the cookie is not set ?** I would like to avoid using reactive authentication to avoid generating `401` on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to strip an unwanted header is with an [interceptor](https://square.github.io/okhttp/interceptors/). Check for the presence of the cookie, and strip the Authorization header if the cookie is present.

Comment: Since the `CookieJar` is set at the `OkHttpClient` level, at the moment of the intercept no cookies are set on the `Request`. There is no method on `Request` to check the cookies, and headers are not yet set with the cookie. I could look directly in the `CookieJar`'s underlying store, but is there a correct way to check the actual cookies of the `Request`?

Comment: After playing around with interceptors, it seems it's possible to do what you were hinting at with a NetworkInterceptor instead of a standard Interceptor.